# Unable to connect to Amazon EC2 without using PPK file

Tags: shell-script

I have a build job which runs on Hudson and synchronizes content from an Amazon AWS server. This is written in shell

I have a PPK file given to me which can establish the connectivity

Here is the problem. The build script I use doesn't establish the connectivity in the code. So, I manually connect the host thro the PPK file using Putty and then run the job, then it works fine

I am new to the shell stuff. Could someone help me out by suggesting how I can establish connectivity using the PPK file in the shell so I do not have to do it manually thro Putty?

Comment: Can you post the portions of the shell script which connect via SSH?

Answer (score 0):

First servers need security to access their resources. so it need **ppk** authentication.

**Establish connectivity using the PPK file** this the actually you need.

For that...

1. Open **putty**
2. Enter **Host name** which is provided by AWS account→ under ec2-instances→description→ IPv4 Public IP . its similar to ip address copy that one and paste it into Host name. Add **ec2-user@** <-- in front of that **ex: ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**
3. Now left side of putty go to → SSH ⇾ Auth ⇾ in the authentication parameter section select **Browse** .ppk file then click on **Open**.
4. it will come with one pop-up click on ok that's it.